# Facebook Share Dialog gives operation couldn’t be completed error on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm trying to post a status using the Facebook iOS API, using the latest SDK version with the following code:

```
FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shareTwitter@2.png"];

FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
photo.image = img;
photo.userGenerated = YES;
FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
content.photos = @[photo];

shareDialog.shareContent = content;
shareDialog.delegate = self;
[shareDialog show];
```

This runs fine, shows the dialog with the picture, I can enter the text of the post, but when I click the post button on the dialog I get the following error:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.Facebook.platform Code=102 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.Facebook.platform error 102.)" UserInfo=0x17027a780 {error_reason=The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBAPIErrorDomain error 100.), error_description=An error occurred during publishing., app_id=000000000000, error_code=102}
```

I've checked the Facebook details in the info.plist which is the top answer for this problem, even copy/pasted the details across. I can make calls to other open graph functions to get profile details and images and they all work fine, so it looks like the basic App details are correct.

Anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 0):

As an update to this, I logged it with Facebook and they are now aware of the bug:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1455166361444107/

Will update if I get a fix or work around